# NFC RFID App that reads a tag then stores it for use later

Tags: javascript

I am creating a very simple app (I think) that will use a mobile phone to read small NFC RFID tags and store the values in a cloud-based database. The problem is, there will be no data connection where the tags are being read.

So my question is, is there an easy way to temporarily store the data, perhaps in a cookie using javascript, until such time as there is a data connection?

Comment: If using html5, simply use local-storage or webSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per enhzflep's comment above, the solution was to use local-storage. Thanks for the assistance.